# Printing out and replacing an updated array values to the table cells

Tags: javascript

I made a simple discount calculation, when a user enter any value, price should be updated. 
I tried many times, but always printed array values are printed in the first row line. I have always the same problem printing an array, i would be appriecate if you give any recommend any videos or articles to understand more this topic as well. Thanks

```
          <input type="number" id="inputValue">
          <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submitBtn">

          <table id='mytable'>
                <thead>
                        <td>Discount Products</td>
                        <td>Price One</td>
                        <td>Price Two</td>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tbody">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Product 1</td>
                        <td class="price-one one"> 100</td>
                        <td class="price-two one">200</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Product 2</td>
                        <td class="price-one one"> 300</td>
                        <td class="price-two one">400</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Product 3</td>
                        <td class="price-one one"> 500</td>
                        <td class="price-two one">600</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Product 4</td>
                        <td class="price-one one"> 700</td>
                        <td class="price-two one">800</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

my script here, I cant update price cells,

```
const submitBtn = document.getElementById('submitBtn');
    submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {   

        const mytable = document.querySelector('#mytable #tbody');

        const inputValue = document.getElementById('inputValue').value;

        const prices = [];

        for (i = 0; i < mytable.rows.length; i++) {

            prices[i] = [];

            for (j = 1; j < mytable.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
                const orginalPrice = mytable.rows[i].cells[j].innerText;

                prices[i].push(parseFloat(orginalPrice) - (inputValue/100 * orginalPrice));
            }
        }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how you print them, but you can set the table content the same way as you are getting them like:

```
mytable.rows[i].cells[j].innerText = parseFloat(orginalPrice) - (inputValue/100 * orginalPrice);
```

You can read more about table cells [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_tr_cells.asp).

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u1m0gjyk/

Answer (score 0):

You are so close. Instead of this line:

```
prices[i].push(parseFloat(orginalPrice) - (inputValue/100 * orginalPrice));
```

which pushes the calculated value into an empty array that isn't connected to the DOM, you want these lines:

```
var newPrice = parseFloat(orginalPrice) - (inputValue/100 * orginalPrice);
mytable.rows[i].cells[j].innerText = newPrice;
```

which add the calculated value into each cell's `innerText` property (i.e. write the values back to the DOM):

```js
const submitBtn = document.getElementById('submitBtn');
    submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {   

        const mytable = document.querySelector('#mytable #tbody');

        const inputValue = document.getElementById('inputValue').value;

        const prices = [];

        for (i = 0; i < mytable.rows.length; i++) {

            prices[i] = [];

            for (j = 1; j < mytable.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
                const orginalPrice = mytable.rows[i].cells[j].innerText;

                var newPrice = parseFloat(orginalPrice) - (inputValue/100 * orginalPrice);
                mytable.rows[i].cells[j].innerText = newPrice;
            }
        }
     });
```

```html
<input type="number" id="inputValue">
          <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submitBtn">

          <table id='mytable'>
                <thead>
                        <td>Discount Products</td>
                        <td>Price One</td>
                        <td>Price Two</td>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tbody">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Product 1</td>
                        <td class="price-one one"> 100</td>
                        <td class="price-two one">200</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Product 2</td>
                        <td class="price-one one"> 300</td>
                        <td class="price-two one">400</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Product 3</td>
                        <td class="price-one one"> 500</td>
                        <td class="price-two one">600</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Product 4</td>
                        <td class="price-one one"> 700</td>
                        <td class="price-two one">800</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```